# nslookup: non-authoritative answer

Tags: networking, firewall, nslookup

When I nslookup behind our firewall i got Non-authoritative answer like this

```
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    sitius.com
Address:  173.44.39.70
```

but if i nslookup from public internet access i got this

```
address1: 173.44.39.70 173.44.39.70.static.quadranet.com
```

I can ping the sitius.com behind the firewall, I cant access their website. 
I did tracert , i stoped somewhere on the way to destination but out of our ISP.
I got a msg like this:

```
Error Code 10060: Connection timeout 

Background: The gateway could not receive a timely response from the website you are trying to access. This might indicate that the network is congested, or that the website is experiencing technical difficulties. 

Date: 2/15/2013 3:50:37 PM [GMT] 

Server: xxxx-fw-01.xxxxxx.com 

Source: Firewall
```

---

issue is that i cant access this site behind our firewall but from public internet access 
is there anyone can help?

Comment: What's the problem that you're trying to resolve? Do you just not understand what a non-authoritative answer is?

Comment: no, the thing is i cant open that page behind our firewall but from public internet accesee

Comment: Then you need to configure your firewall or content filter to let you reach it. This has nothing to do with DNS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### About the non-authoritative response

This is normal. Non-authoritative answers means that the DNS server that answered your query isn't authoritative for the zone that you're requesting. This is what most results return, since you're probably receiving data cached from your local DNS servers.

This isn't an issue and it's how DNS is designed to work.

### About the site not being accessible

You probably have a proxy, content filter, or firewall rule preventing you from accessing this site. Since the non-authoritative and authoritative responses are the same, you don't have a DNS problem.

Comment: I need to find out why i cant access this site behind our firewall?

Comment: Talk to your firewall admin.